# Live Code Android Test: Installation of app failed: rm failed for

Tags: android, livecode

I created an app using the Live Code App Design Kit and I want to Test it on the 
Android device emulator using the Test button in Live Code.  Eventually, I want to 
run it on my Nexus 7.  I followed all of the instructions in the "How do I Become 
an Android Developer on a PC?" lesson/tutorial provided by Live Code. Everything 
seems to have worked on the Java SDK and Android SDK installs, I configured a virtual 
device and started it, I configured Live Code for Android support, did the 
Standalone application settings, and the Test button is live.

A box appears on Live Code after asking Live Code to "Test" the Android standalone.

It goes through a series of steps, displays what it is doing, and gets successfully 
through "Building classes, Preparing package, Assembling assets..., Finalizing package, ..   and finally displays "installing app on target device."

Then an error dialog box appears:

"Installation of app failed: rm failed for 
/data/local/tmp/tmp16, No such file or directory

failed to copy 'C:/Users/Mark/AppData/LOcal/Temp/tmp16'
to '/data/local/tmp/tmp16': No such file or directory"

I did a number of searches and didn't find out what is going wrong or what I need to 
change in any of my settings, etc. to make it work.

Any suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: I never had this message before.. Did you try to run something on your Android VM? Does the VM have a SD card or some other memory configured?

Comment: I did have a SD card configured.  I have not tried running anything else on the Android VM.

Comment: What version of LiveCode are you using?

Comment: I'm using Live Code Community 6.6.1

Answer (score 0):

I just tested an old stack on 6.6.1 and the avd manager on Mac OSX.
It worked fine and started up successfully.

This was my configuration:
[image: LC 6.6.1 Community]

[image: AVD Manager]